# JavaScript FloodFIll Slow

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am learning JavaScript and decided to work on a FloodFIll Project, specifically mimicking the bucket fill tool like in Microsoft Word. I first tried using recursion, but it would exceed the stack size so I tried an iterative approach. However, it is really slow. I actually don't mind it being slow because I want to see it spread out. Is there any way to do this with the code I have now? Thanks.

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'); // goes through doc and grabes canvas element
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;
let Stack = [];

var c = canvas.getContext('2d'); // magic paintprush to draw 2d element
   
   function isEqual(a, b) 
   { 
     // if length is not equal 
     if(a.length!=b.length) {
         return false;
     }
     else { 
     // comapring each element of array 
      for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
       if(a[i]!=b[i]) {
          return false;
           }
       }
       return true; 
     } 
   } 


// Updates the graph 
function UpdateGraph(old_color, row_num, col_num, numRows, numCols){

   if (row_num + 1 < numRows){
       var pixel1 = c.getImageData(row_num+1, col_num, 1, 1);
       var data1 = pixel1.data;
       var pixel_color1 = [data1[0], data1[1], data1[2], data1[3]];
       if(isEqual(pixel_color1, old_color)){
           c.fillRect( row_num+1, col_num, 1, 1 ); 
           Stack.push([row_num + 1, col_num]);
       
       }
       if(col_num+1 < numCols){
           var pixel2 = c.getImageData(row_num+1, col_num+1, 1, 1);
           var data2 = pixel2.data;
           var pixel_color2 = [data2[0], data2[1], data2[2], data2[3]];
           if (isEqual(pixel_color2, old_color)) {
               c.fillRect( row_num+1, col_num+1, 1, 1 ); 
               Stack.push([row_num + 1, col_num+1]);
           }
       }
       if(col_num-1 >= 0){
           var pixel3 = c.getImageData(row_num+1, col_num-1, 1, 1);
           var data3 = pixel3.data;
           var pixel_color3 = [data3[0], data3[1], data3[2], data3[3]];
           if(isEqual(pixel_color3, old_color)){
               c.fillRect( row_num+1, col_num-1, 1, 1 ); 
               Stack.push([row_num + 1, col_num-1]);
           }
       }

   }
   if(row_num - 1 >= 0){
       var pixel4 = c.getImageData(row_num-1, col_num, 1, 1);
       var data4 = pixel4.data;
       var pixel_color4 = [data4[0], data4[1], data4[2], data4[3]];
       if(isEqual(pixel_color4, old_color)){
           c.fillRect( row_num-1, col_num, 1, 1 ); 
           Stack.push([row_num - 1, col_num]);
       }
       if(col_num+1 < numCols){
           var pixel5 = c.getImageData(row_num-1, col_num+1, 1, 1);
           var data5 = pixel5.data;
           var pixel_color5 = [data5[0], data5[1], data5[2], data5[3]];
           if (isEqual(pixel_color5, old_color)) {
               c.fillRect( row_num-1, col_num+1, 1, 1 ); 
               Stack.push([row_num - 1, col_num+1]);
              
           }
       }
       if(col_num-1 >= 0){
           var pixel6 = c.getImageData(row_num-1, col_num-1, 1, 1);
           var data6 = pixel6.data;
           var pixel_color6 = [data6[0], data6[1], data6[2], data6[3]];
           if(isEqual(pixel_color6, old_color)){
               c.fillRect( row_num-1, col_num-1, 1, 1 ); 
               Stack.push([row_num - 1, col_num-1]);
           }
       }
   }
   if(col_num - 1 >= 0){
       var pixel7 = c.getImageData(row_num, col_num-1, 1, 1);
       var data7 = pixel7.data;
       var pixel_color7 = [data7[0], data7[1], data7[2], data7[3]];
       if(isEqual(pixel_color7, old_color)){
           c.fillRect( row_num, col_num-1, 1, 1 );
           Stack.push([row_num, col_num-1]);
       }
   }
   if(col_num + 1 < numCols){
       var pixel8 = c.getImageData(row_num, col_num+1, 1, 1);
       var data8 = pixel8.data;
       var pixel_color8 = [data8[0], data8[1], data8[2], data8[3]];
       if(isEqual(pixel_color8, old_color)){
           c.fillRect( row_num, col_num+1, 1, 1 );
           Stack.push([row_num, col_num+1]);
       }
   }

   
}

function getMousePosition(canvas, event) { 
   let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); 
   let x = event.clientX - rect.left; 
   let y = event.clientY - rect.top; 
   return [x,y];
} 

let new_color = [255, 0, 0, 1];
c.fillStyle = "rgba("+new_color[0]+","+new_color[1]+","+new_color[2]+","+new_color[3]+")";
let row_num, col_num;
let canvasElem = document.querySelector("canvas"); 
var numRows = canvas.height;
var numCols = canvas.width;
 
canvasElem.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) 
{ 
   let coords = getMousePosition(canvasElem, e); 
   row_num = Number(coords[0]);
   col_num = Number(coords[1]);
   var pixel = c.getImageData(row_num, col_num, 1, 1).data;
   console.log(row_num);
   console.log(col_num);
   c.fillRect( row_num, col_num, 1, 1 );
   var old_color= [pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2], pixel[3]];
   Stack.push([row_num, col_num]);
   while(Stack.length){
       UpdateGraph(old_color, row_num, col_num, numRows, numCols);
       let newPos = Stack.pop();
       row_num = newPos[0];
       col_num = newPos[1];
       
   }
});
```

Comment: Never call getImageData several times from the same state. Call it once, to get an ImageData containing the full size of your canvas, then walk through this unique ImageData.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you for your response. How would I exactly walk through this unique ImageData? Do you mind showing me an example? Thanks